# Creating an Instagram-like photo feed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, feed

I'm trying to make a photo feed for an app I'm making, similar to Instagram's:

[Instagram photo feed](http://www.fuelyourphotography.com/files/photo-1.PNG)

I've created a preliminary version using a UITableView for the feed, but it's becoming a hassle dealing with the dynamic nature of each cell. The number of likes and comments along with the comment text itself will determine how tall the cell is. I used UITextViews to draw the comment and like text, and approximate the cell height and positioning using the UITextViews' text with sizeWithFont. This solution seems very imprecise and has a lot of downsides.

I was thinking about using a UIWebView for the entire feed as an alternate solution. It would make positioning the like and comment text extremely simple, along with the ability to have variable font in the text as seen in Instagram. I haven't really used UIWebViews extensively, so I'm not sure how easy or hard it would be to create the whole feed this way.

Should I continue using my UITableView solution or look into redoing it all using a UIWebView?

Comment: Can you explain why you believe it's imprecise?  It would help me understand your problem.  Thanks.

Comment: It just feels odd to approximate how much space text would take up instead of using actual sizes. I was having a problem before where the text views wouldn't show up in the exact correct spot initially, but then pop into place when the table is reloaded after an image is downloaded, for example. I've since fixed this problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app, I've got a UITableViewCell that dynamically adjusts its height based on the amount of text in the cell. I think it might help answer your question.

Here's the trick: There is no need to "approximate text sizes" --- check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for the method `[NSString sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:]`

```
maximumSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.bounds.size.width - TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN * 2.0, 
                                 MAXIMUM_TEXT_HEIGHT);
        textStringSize = [textLabel.text sizeWithFont:textLabel.font 
                                    constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                        lineBreakMode:textLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

So let's take a simple example where you want 10 pixels of whitespace above the label, and 15 pixels of whitespace below the label. You'd then generate a `CGRect` with the measurements above, with a height of 25 pixels added to the `textStringSize.height` value generated above.

Using this method means that your UITableViewCells will scale up and down nicely, regardless of the size of the comments in the different labels.

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up doing. I just figured there would be a nicer solution, as my code is not the best looking due to all the frame resizing and positioning going on in each cell.

Comment: Your code can get a lot nicer to manage if you avoid hardcoding numbers, and instead use `#define` to set up the number of pixels you'd like to use around the text. For example, I use `#define kDefaultFontPadding 10;` to say that there should be 10 pixels of padding around the label. Hope that helps clean up your code --- it means that you can reference that single number from multiple places, and then experiment with different values quite easily by changing the number in one place.

Comment: constrainedToSize is depreciated in iOS7 whats the logic behind using/suggesting deprecated api's. @sbezboro you can use boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleIdendifer=@"item";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdendifer];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:simpleIdendifer];

    }


    [[cell textLabel] setText:self.str];
    [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];
    [[cell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]];
        return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //add your table view cell content here
    NSString *string = self.str;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]};

    CGRect frame = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil];
    return ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(frame)+TableViewCellPadding);
}
```